# <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> working with webkit?

Tags: css, webkit, cross-browser

I ask this question because I'm not able to test it at the moment.

Is it possible to make iexplorer 8 webkit (css based rounded corners) compatible with the following meta tag?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Any info would be great!

Comment: IE 8 uses Trident, not WebKit.

Comment: Isn't this a way to make it webkit compatible?

Comment: No, it is a way to force IE8 into "standards mode" and to disable the compatibility view button in the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to make Internet Explorer 8 follow `-webkit` CSS properties with the above described `<meta>` tag.

Internet Explorer 8 uses *Trident* as its rendering engine, not *Webkit*. Therefore you cannot make it render pages the exact way *Webkit* does.

The above `<meta>` tag is to force Internet Explorer 8 and onwards to render the page using rendering code from Internet Explorer 8.

In fact, using this tag will prevent [`border-radius` from working in Internet Explorer 9](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/11/18/an-early-look-at-ie9-for-developers.aspx) as it will tell Internet Explorer 9 to render the page as Internet Explorer 8 did (without `border-radius` support).

---

However, you can use a JavaScript solution such as [CurvyCorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/) to "add" support for the `border-radius` CSS3 property until [Internet Explorer 9 is released](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/11/18/an-early-look-at-ie9-for-developers.aspx). Note that while this is approximate the behavior of `border-radius` in unsupported browsers, it might cause other unforeseen problems.

Comment: It is possible with Chrome Frame, however.